# the probability of happening the event B is $3$/$4$,Then the probability that event A does not happen is:

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are two equally likely events and the probability of happening the event $B$ is $\frac 34$,then the probability that event $A$ does not happen is:

A) $\frac 34$  B)$\frac 14$  C) $\frac 23$  D) $\frac 13$

My approach:

$P(B)=\frac 34$

$P(\neg A)=P(B)=\frac 34$

Where am I wrong? Can anyone give me any hint?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are equally likely and if the probability that $B$ occurs is $3/4$, then...?

Comment: Hint: do not assume that A and B are mutually exclusive. There is nothing about that in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are two equally likely events, then $$p(A^c)=p(B^c)=1-p(B)=1-\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: How P(not happening A)=P(Not happening B).It is not  clear.

Comment: If they are two equally likely event, then $p(A)=p(B)$. Therefore, $p(A^c)=1-p(A)=1-p(B)=p(B^c)$.